# Manga where a daughter pays off her father's debt?

Tags: tsubaki-chou

I remember reading it a few months back, I have forgotten the name of it and some parts of it are quite fuzzy to me now. Can someone help. It has been on my mind for a while and I have been desperately trying to find it!

- The manga was about a young high-schooler girl whose father was in
  debt. Her father basically leaves her to pay it off himself? Or
  something along the lines of that by working on a boat but something
  happens to his back as part of the plot in the manga.
- Then, she becomes a live-in housekeeper for a writer/author as she
  gets recommended to him by someone. She did so in order to help her
  father with the debt. She also tried getting a part-time job as a
  hostess/waitress at a place. However, she's supposedly underage but
  lies about her age.
- While she works she recognizes this boy whom she met and fought over some
  kind of food product/rice at the grocery store when they were younger.
  She finds out he is the son of the person who has hired her at the store.
- Unexpectedly, the author/writer comes in with the person who
  recommended her to him. The author/writer gets mad at her because
  she's underage and working there. He asks if the money he pays her is
  not enough.
- She begs the boy to not tell his mother that she is underage? There's
  also this part somewhere in the manga where her panties are stolen by
  a weird man and the author gets her panties back for her. I also
  think she realized she was developing feelings for this
  author/writer.

The manga is also currently on-going as far as I remember!

Thanks in advance xoxo :) <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manga you ask about is **[Tsubaki-chou Lonely Planet](http://myanimelist.net/manga.php?id=89562)**.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @x3kaye. ;)